# File contents are wiped when trying to read from Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to read a file using the Scanner, however, all the contents of the file are wiped, and then it reads nothing. Here are the methods I've ran in succession, in my Main method:

```
private static Scanner x;
private static Formatter y;

public void openMainFile(String name){
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("main.mcmm");
        y = new Formatter("main.mcmm");
    }catch(Exception e){
        GUI.error(2);
    }
}
```

This method runs perfectly fine

```
public void readModMainFile(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
        Main.name = x.next();
        Main.ver = x.nextFloat();
        Main.base = x.nextBoolean();
        Main.dev = x.next();
        Main.date = x.next();
    }
}
```

After this method runs, the file is empty, and the 'Main.-' variables don't have any values.

Comment: What is `y = new Formatter("main.mcmm");` supposed to do?

Comment: That's for writing data to the file. It has no relevance to this.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it has. It wipes your file clean, as specified in the javadoc. `The name of the file to use as the destination of this formatter. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.`

Comment: Didn't format fork with streams? What a better approach for the string formatter.

Answer (score 2):

Don't open the same file for reading and writing at the same time. Write into a temporary file first, then rename it. Alternatively, you can read the whole file first, store everything, close the `Scanner` and then you can overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Formatter` is truncating the output file every time. From your comments in this post, you indicate that the number of variables will remain constant. You could use a temporary file to achieve this (+1 to @biziclop):

```
File inputFile = new File("main.mcmm");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("main.mcmm",".temp");
Formatter y = new Formatter(tempFile);

y.format("%s", name);
 // more reading & formatting, etc.

y.close();
scanner.close();
inputFile.delete();
tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

Remember to close both the  `Scanner` and `Formatter` so that the input & output files can be deleted & renamed respectively.

Comment: I agree, was going to comment but you beat me to it.

Comment: Didn't wipe the file, however, gives me a:  java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: at the: Main.verMod = x.nextFloat(); line

Comment: Check the format of the input file, It looks like its expecting a `float` but isn't find one that position.

Comment: @Reimeus This code will simply append the output to the end of the input file. I don't think that's what OP wanted, although I'm just guessing.

Comment: @biziclop Yes, I don't see where `y` is used so hard to say.

Comment: There is a float so I don't know, I'll look in to it.

Comment: y is used in another method to write data to the file

Comment: @user1580616 Should the number of variables the same in the file remain the same? i.e. Do you want to update the variables or 'grow' the file by appending to it?